# make HTML generated by content scripts of extensions inaccessible to page scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to show HTML elements generated by extension content scripts over/inside the window area but make them inaccessible for site scripts so the page could not potentially detect/modify them through DOM. Are there any techniques specific for extension development which would allow to do this? Like layering or so

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is an `iframe` with a cross-domain `src` but I'm not sure whether that's an option in your context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any special Chrome Extension techniques for this. As you'll read [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), JavaScript injected via a content script is automatically sandboxed, or separated from the JavaScript on a web page, but this is not the case for HTML -- the DOM elements are shared between the page scripts and the injected content scripts.